# Spring Cloud Exit Codes & docker restart

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I've an application that uses config server within docker:

https://github.com/KramKroc/eurekafirstdiscovery

I want to switch the docker restart policy from **always** to **on-failure** in order to add a cap on the amount of restart my app does. on-failure will only restart a docker container is a **non-zero exit code** is returned.

When my application is starting, the config-server will not have fully started, and so the application will shut down. It does so with a zero exit code. Is there any way to modify this to return a non-zero exit code?

Comment: Setting en exit code doesn't have anything to do with cloud, just boot. Maybe http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#exit-org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext-org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator...-

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for the pointer to the exit functionality.I played around with ExitCodeExceptionMapper etc but for them, you need to have your application already started (as I understand it). When a spring app is configured with spring.cloud.config and the config server is not available on start up, then your application is not started, e.g. in terms of context events you go from ApplicationPreparedEvent > ApplicationReadyEvent > ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent > ApplicationFailedEvent, i.e. your mainline is not invoked. Is there another way to set the exit code at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an issue when run spring boot apps from java -jar that was introduced in 1.3.2 as reported here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5922

This will be fixed in 1.3.6 and is already working in 1.4.0.M2